# How to get the control of MoviePlayer while we are streaming video using WebView

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiwebview, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am trying to show YouTube videos on my application. How can I stop/pause the playing movie player after a particular amount of time. I am using/loding the url in webview rather than MPMoviePlayer. If anyone knows the solution please share. I need to implement it in one of my app.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As you will not get any access to the actual MPMoviePlayerController and since no notifications will be visible outside the UIWebView, you will be locked into using javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

As you will not get any access to the actual MPMoviePlayerController and since no notifications will be visible outside the UIWebView, you will be locked into using javascript code - that is, stay within the UIWebView scope of actions.

How and if such things are exactly implemented/able using javascript, I do not know.